# cache data from database on application startup

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot

I am trying to build a cache for a web application, below is the above code which I have so far. This cache has to be loaded on application startup.

```
@Service
public class CacheBuilder {

    private MultiKeyMap cache = new MultiKeyMap();

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationDAO configurationDAO;

    public void loadConfigurations() {

        Map<String, Collection<Config>> map = null;
        try {
            if (cache != null || cache.isEmpty()) {

                map = configDAO.loadConfigs();
                map.forEach((k, v) -> {
                    v.forEach((c) -> {
                        cache.put(k, c.getAttributeName(), c.getAttributeValue());
                    });
                });
            }

        } catch (DaoException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Object getValue(String key1, String key2) {
        return cache.get(key1, key2);
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        if (cache != null) {
            cache.clear();
        }
    }

    public String printCache() {

        return cache.toString();
    }

}
```

I am currently using spring boot application and I am trying to improve my pseudo code base and what I would like to have is.

1. the loadConfigurations() method should not be exposed to anyone, so that no one accidentally calls it.
2. I want to ideally have a single instance of this class created with methods as static ? would that be the best thing to do ?

If I do step 2, how do I achieve step 1 ?

Can anyone please suggest me some pointers ?

Comment: For point 1) as you do not do anything if the `cache` is already loaded, why is this a concern.  Also, where do you initialize `cache` so you don't get a NPE?  Try doing as a Singleton?

Comment: I am calling the loadConfigurations() method from a seperate class. Can you share a sample code via Singleton ?

Comment: Brief question: why does the buildin Cache abstraction not work for you?

Comment: I did some reading on that but I am not able to vision how I can do the following with that. What I want to do is, load the data from the database and store it in MultikeyMap datasturcture, then create a method getValue(key k1, key k2) to fetch the data. can build n cache do that ?